# "Fingerprinting" traits of a horse

Tags: single-word-requests

When a horse is being registered with the country's official registry, a clerk arrives to the stable to file the necessary paperwork. This process involves writing down the owner's data, the horse's parentage, measuring height at withers, and noting down locations of the special "fingerprinting features" that are unique to individual horse and remain constant through its whole life - the fur pattern along the mane.

Specifically, the **locations where the fur converges** forming a small tip, **diverges revealing a little skin**, or **forms a small whirl**, clockwise or anticlockwise

These are noted down with respective symbols on a chart of horse's neck, filed with the registry, and allow to uniquely identify the horse, say, in case of theft and dispute of ownership.

What are these "features" called in English?

Comment: These are generally called biometrics, but in specific with respect to hair patterns, sometimes *cowlick* applies.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: I believe cowlick would apply to the convergence point. There was something like 'balding' about divergence, and the remaining were whirls or whorls or something like that. But I might just as well be imagining things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called ***swirls*** or ***whorls***.

> **Swirls on horses are the equine equivalent of fingerprints on humans.** With no two patterns alike, they are like stamps marking each individual’s unique identity.
>
> In a number of breeds swirl patterns are used as identification for horses: the Arabian Horse Association requires a record of swirls as identification for racing, and the American Quarter Horse Association uses swirls as a means of identification for solid color horses. When Thoroughbreds are registered, part of the procedure is to record the swirl patterns on the face and on both sides of the neck.
>
> A swirl, or whorl, as it is also called, can be defined as a distinctive pattern in the lay of hair on an animal, often having the design of whirling, flexible spokes rotating about a center.
>
> <sub>*Getting in TTouch with Your Horse: how to assess and influence personality, potential, and performance* 
> by Linda Tellington-Jones</sub>

There is even a name for the study of hair swirls or whorls in horses: ***swirlology*** or ***whorlology***.

Further readings:

- http://foxpointfarm.com/Swirlology.html
- http://horsemanship-journal.com/theory/whorlology/

Comment: Nice, but there are names for specific types of these swirls/whorls. And while your first link lists these, I'm not finding them particularly reliable, because "Swirlology/Whorlology" really seems like a pseudoscience, treating the patterns as indication of some inborn traits: "A swirl directly between the eyes is normal. High swirls usually goes with a more active mind;" "Double or triple swirls indicate multiple personalities."

Comment: @SF.: [This book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7bgKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA379&dq=equine+fingerprints&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xOgQVd3kHoOQyQTuwoDACw&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=equine%20fingerprints&f=false) mentions that *chestnuts, cowlicks and dimples* are the fingerprints of the horses. They are mentioned under "body markings" title. [Another book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CxBxAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&dq=equine+fingerprints&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xOgQVd3kHoOQyQTuwoDACw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=equine%20fingerprints&f=false) talks about eyes of the horses and says that every *granula iridica* is unique.

Comment: Just a note *chestnuts* are yet different traits - "vestigal thumbs" - small lumps of dry tissue (resembling scabs a little) that may or may not appear near ankles of horses and take different shapes and sizes if they do.